Group cells dynamically based on either indentation or content
My accounting software exports most recent data into a spreadsheet which contains lot of data that is hard to analyze without grouping it.
I'd like to group rows based on similarity to the row above it (Or potentially based on indent, but that might be more difficult).
For example, there is a Discounts and promotions section which has several sub-items (sometimes an item might get added, so in the xample below, at some random point there could be 4 rows of sub-content vs. 3). At the bottom is the Total for that section.
The total row always has the same exact title  with the word "Total " appended to the front.
    Discounts & promotions
        Discounts & promotions - Facebook (via Shopify)
        Discounts & promotions - Shopify - name
        Discounts & promotions - Shopify - name - gift card giveaways
    Total Discounts & promotions

Here is a link to some sample data.
Is there a script that can go through the whole sheet and group sections by logic - if this row has the same exact content as this other row + the word Total at the front, then group them.
(Also first I need the script to remove all groups - this is working, and last I need the script to collapse all groups,this is also working)
Here is the code I tried. Nothing is happening to the data in the spreadsheet.
function removeAllGroups1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Daily");
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let d = sh.getRowGroupDepth(i + 1);
    if (d >= 1) {
      sh.getRowGroup(i + 1, d).remove()
    }
  });
}

function groupRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();

  let previousValue = "";
  let groupStartRow = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const currentValue = values[i][0];

    // Check if the current value is a "Total" version of the previous value
    if (currentValue.startsWith("Total ") && currentValue.substring(6) === previousValue) {
      // Group the current row with the previous row
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    } else {
      // Reset the group start row
      groupStartRow = i + 1;
    }

    previousValue = currentValue;
  }
}

function collapse() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Daily');
   let lastRow = sh.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  
  for (let row = 1; row < lastRow; row++) {
    let depth = sh.getRowGroupDepth(row);
    if (depth < 1) continue;
    sh.getRowGroup(row, depth).collapse();
  }
}


"Is there a script..." is not the most proper wording for a question about a specific practical problem unique to programming. Please [edit] the question to make it focused on a particular issue of programming. Regarding the code in the question, please include a [mcve] limited to the programming problem to be solved.

On the sheet="Copy of Daily", rows are intented. But the script addresses "Daily" where the rows are NOT indented. On sheet="What I Need", the rows are intended. Would you please clarify the issues regarding intenting.

1) What is the meaning of THIS CONTINUES UNTIL ROW 500... at the bottom of "Daily"? 2) Is the information in Column A, rows 72 and 73 always generated like this? 3) Net Operating Profit Why isn't there data on this row? (row#70)

Use forEach() and indexOf() functions for row grouping
Consider this alternative answer, which should align with your desired outcome. This script will group rows according to your specifications.
Code:
// Group Rows Matching from the first and last.
function groupRows() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  removeAllGroups1(range)

  let data = []
  for (let i = 4; i < values.length; i++) {
    // To lower case the current value of the values.
    const currentValue = values[i][0].toLowerCase();
    const toSearch = `total ${currentValue}`;
    // Map out all the values to lowered Cases.
    const lcase = values.map(x => x[0].toLowerCase());
    // Locating the index of the matching value of the current value.
    let index = lcase.indexOf(toSearch);

    // to check if there is same name of the cell
    data.forEach(x => {
      if (x[1] == index) {
        for (let i = index + 1; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (toSearch == lcase[i]) {
            index = i
          }
        }
      }
    })

    if (index != -1 && index != undefined) {
      data.push([i + 1, index])
    }
  }
  // Each Iteration of Group Depth
  data.forEach(x => {
    sheet.getRange(x[0], 1, x[1] - x[0] + 1).shiftRowGroupDepth(1)
  });
}

function removeAllGroups1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Daily");
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let d = sh.getRowGroupDepth(i + 1);
    if (d >= 1) {
      sh.getRowGroup(i + 1, d).remove()
    }
  });
}

Sample Output:

References:

forEach()
indexOf()
toLowerCase()


That seems to be working, but note that the const toSearch = 'total ${currentValue}' || 'other ${currentValue}' bit will set toSearch to the first expression and ignore the other. Further, you cannot use conditionals with Array.indexOf(). See Logical OR (||) and Array.indexOf().

@doubleunary Thanks for the heads-up. It was my mistake; I forgot to remove that part of the line. I've updated my code and corrected the value of the variable.

@leylou This worked for me thank you  (all of the others didn't seem to work). I'm not sure how to give you credit, I am new here.

@Shawna Gwin Krasts Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer. How to accept answer

You can remove existing row groups much faster with Range.shiftRowGroupDepth().
The labels in sample data include two occurrences of 'Other cost of sales' with matching 'Total' rows. To group these rows correctly, you need to keep track of 'Total' rows that have already been matched, and look for another matching label instead.
Use Array.findIndex() and Array.includes(), like this:
'use strict';

/**
* Groups rows by matching labels in a range to the next matching label that has a 'Total ' prefix.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} range The one-column range with row labels. Defaults to Daily!A5:A.
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function groupRows(keyRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Daily!A5:A')) {
  const sheet = keyRange.getSheet();
  sheet.getDataRange().shiftRowGroupDepth(-Infinity);
  const rowStart = keyRange.getRow();
  const keys = keyRange.getDisplayValues().flat().map(k => k.trim());
  const endIndices = [];
  keys.forEach((key, indexStart) => {
    const numRows = keys.slice(indexStart).findIndex((k, i) => k === `Total ${key}` && !endIndices.includes(indexStart + i));
    if (numRows !== -1) {
      endIndices.push(indexStart + numRows);
      sheet.getRange(rowStart + indexStart + 1, 1, numRows).shiftRowGroupDepth(1).collapseGroups();
    }
  });
}

The function iterates labels and searches down from each row, finding occurrences of matching 'Total' rows. In the event of repeated labels, it will match each such repeated label to the closest 'Total' label that has not yet been matched. Embedding takes place automatically when necessary.

See
Array.findIndex(),
Array.includes() and
Range.shiftRowGroupDepth().

You want to group rows on a P&L based on a "cell value" being followed by a subsequent "Total" cell value. For example, "Sales" and "Total Sales".
Consider this answer.

Logic

removeExistingGroups("Daily") - delete existing groups; re-uses the OP's code
var data = dataRange.getValues().flat() get the values in Column A as a 1D array
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){ - loop through the rows

var title = data[i] - get the row value
var totalTitle = "Total "+title - create an equivalent "Total" value
var index = data.indexOf(totalTitle) - use indexOf to find a match for the "Total value"
if a match is NOT found - do nothing
if a match IS found identify the range to be grouped

var groupRange = sheet.getRange(dataRow,1,matchRow-dataRow)
groupRange.shiftRowGroupDepth(1); - group the range






function groupSheetRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily")

  // delete existing groups
  removeExistingGroups("Daily")
  
  // first row of data
  var firstRow = 5
  // get the last row of data
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  
  // get the data range for column A
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow,1,lastRow-firstRow+1-4,1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
  var data = dataRange.getValues().flat()
  // Logger.log(data) // DEBUG

  // loop through the data to find matches
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var title = data[i]
    var totalTitle = "Total "+title
    // indexOf returns -1 is no match is found,
    // or the array index IF a match is found
    var index = data.indexOf(totalTitle)
    // test for result
    if (index == -1){
      // can't find a match, 
       // Logger.log("DEBUG: NO MATCH: i = "+i+", Title = "+title+", total Title = "+totalTitle+", index = "+index)
    }else{
      // found a match
      var dataRow = i+firstRow
      var matchRow = index+firstRow
      var matchValue = data[index]
      var groupRange = sheet.getRange(dataRow,1,matchRow-dataRow)
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: MATCH FOUND: i = "+i+", Title = "+title+", row = "+dataRow+", total Title = "+totalTitle+", index = "+index+", matched row = "+matchRow+", matched value = "+matchValue+", range to be grouped = "+groupRange.getA1Notation())
      // The row grouping depth is increased by 1.
      groupRange.shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    }
  }
}

function removeExistingGroups(sheet) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let d = sh.getRowGroupDepth(i + 1);
    if (d >= 1) {
      sh.getRowGroup(i + 1, d).remove()
    }
  });
}


SAMPLE - OUTPUT


FWIW, This answer is not as brief nor as elegant as the answer by @doubleunary. having said that, there is no "execution time penalty" for using this script.
